# Updated php now having issues with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin

We have an amazon linux server. It was running php 5.3 we wanted to update to 5.6 to see if it would solve an issue with a plugin on our wordpress installation. I installed php 5.6 and am now having issues getting back into phpMyAdmin and our wordpress site which I think isn't loading because of the database problem.

When I go to /phpMyAdmin I get Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server.

I've found a few threads on here suggesting things such as placing the following in my phpMyAdmin.conf file:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #Require ip 127.0.0.1
       #Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

I have tried this, also I added Allow from 'my static ip'. I have also restarted httpd still nothing. The other thing that is happening is I'm getting the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page when I go to what should be our wordpress website, I'm not sure if these are the same problem but I assume it is related.

The website in question is calendar.childmags.com.au

Comment: Anything in the Apache error log?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to off the strict mode. For the temporary solution you can use 
For all DB:_

```
SET @@global.sql_mode=''
```

For current DB:-

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

Comment: I just did these and It's still exactly the same.

Comment: I just checked and there is no phpMyAdmin folder inside usr/share?